# Cordova Build.json password security

Tags: cordova, apk, signing

I've had issues getting cordova to prompt me for the password to the storePassword and password fields in the build.json file when building and signing my apks. The solution I've turned to is to enter them in the build.json file.

My question: is there any security issue when manually entering passwords into build.json (such as the passwords somehow being included in the actual signed apk, etc.)?

I have build.json in the root of my cordova project so it is automatically detected and all I have to do is:

```
cordova build android --release
```

...which is why I've gone this route (it just works). I know this might seem like a silly question, but the Cordova docs state:

> "For release signing, passwords can be excluded and the build system
>   will issue a prompt asking for the password."

...which implies that for some reason passwords shouldn't be entered into build.json for release.

Comment: this issue is duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349848/cordova-6-4-0-android-error-when-building-release-apk
As of now this seems to be a bug, my problem with including the password in `build.json` is when using some VCS (e.g. git). If your repository is compromised....

Comment: Thanks for the link. I wasn't asking whether there was a bug because I knew it wasn't prompting me for the password. I wanted to know if there's a security issue in putting the password in the build.json (even if only until the build is complete).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the passwords somehow being included in the actual signed apk

The `build.json` file won't get included in the final apk that gets built. You can verify this by unzipping the apk to cross-check.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the main reason is to avoid storing a password in a plain text in `build.json` and instead type it in console:

```
{
    "android": {
        "debug": {
            "keystore": "../android.keystore",
            "storePassword": "android",
            "alias": "mykey1",
            "password" : "password",
            "keystoreType": ""
        },
        "release": {
            "keystore": "../android.keystore",
            "storePassword": "",
            "alias": "mykey2",
            "password" : "password",
            "keystoreType": ""
        }
    }
}
```

or take from an environment variable:
`cordova run android --release -- --keystore=../my-release-key.keystore --storePassword=%STORE_PASS% --alias=mykey2 --password=password`.