# Unable to create signed build after upgrading android version in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have been working with < 5 version of android platform in my hybrid application. now I updated the version by removing first `ionic platform rm android` and then `ionic platform add android@5.0.0`. With previous version I was able to create signed release build with this command without any problem

```
cordova build android --release --buildConfig=build.json -- --gradleArg=-PcdvMinSdkVersion=16
```

but after adding this version `android@5.0.0`, when I run the build command it gives me  `android-release-unsigned.apk`

**Note:** I am using same keystore as previously I was using

**Update:**

```
{ 
"android": {
        "release": {
        "keystore": "C:\\Path\\To\\Keystores\\theapp.keystore",
        "storePassword": "",
        "alias": "thealias",
        "password" : "",
        "keystoreType": ""
    } 
}
```

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349848/cordova-6-4-0-android-error-when-building-release-apk/40884993#40884993

Comment: @daserge The link you mentioned talks about issue related to android@6.0.0 but the question is about android@5.0.0

Comment: Right. I'm just not sure when this has broken - it must be some Gradle update. @Qadeer - have you figured this out?

Comment: Have you tried to manually zipalign the apk? Something like `zipalign -v 4 platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release.apk`. This gives a android-release.apk which can be used for the store.

Comment: @daserge then how to update gradle

Comment: @JanP sorry I don't know the way you are referring.

Comment: Why downvote? isn't it a issue?

Comment: I didn't down vote, must be someone else. Maybe this gives more info? https://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html, also about zipalign

Comment: @Qadeer Try applying [this patch](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/351/files#diff-c37e154983ced1f8b9a9fa3754f78542R267) to your build.gradle file.

Comment: This link can help you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449512/how-to-create-signed-apk-file-using-cordova-command-line-interface